# javascript - string & numeric value comparision

Tags: javascript, sql, hana

Below is the code, I am using to get the aggregation total count, for a specific `groupby` condition. I am initially, getting all the records with the filter condition, then based on the `groupby` column, I am getting the count for each distinct value of that group by column.

```
allRecords.filter(
  function(r){
    return r[groupByCondition.column] == groupByCondition.value;
  }
).length;
```

This works pretty well, if the `groupbyColumn` has a numeric value. It is not getting the aggregate total count, when the group by column has characters.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: could you provide two examples, one with numeric value, one without. I'm not sure to understand what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: inside filter function '3' and 3 are different you need to parseInt(val,10)

Comment: or `return r[groupByCondition.column].toString() == groupByCondition.value.toString();` (They may not be integers)

Comment: do you mean that the filter fails if `r[groupByCondition.column]` returns a numerical value?

Comment: or just `return +r[groupByCondition.column] === +groupByCondition.value;` as long as they are numbers (and meant to be numbers)

Comment: this works, well, when the column has 100/'110' but fails when it has abc

Comment: Can you post a sample of `allRecords` and `groupByCondition`?

Comment: allrecords ={col1=abc, col1=xyz}. groupby conddition (col1=abc)

Comment: what you're writing here does not correspond to the structure in your post (`groupByCondition` should have a `column` property and a `value` property).

Comment: column property = col1,col2.....value property = ab cd, xy-z,.....

Comment: We need an example that's close to reality and not just pseudocode ... do you mean `allRecords = [{"col1": "abc", "col2": "xyz"}, {"col1": "cde", "col2": "xyz"}]` and `groupByCondition = {"col1": "abc"}`?

Comment: yes Marc, correct. The data looks like what you said.

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt`/`parseFloat` to convert strings to numbers

```
return parseInt(r[groupByCondition.column]) == parseInt(groupByCondition.value);
```

Comment: He uses '==' and not '===' so '3' == 3 resolves to true. In the light of this, how can your answer be the solution to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `groupByCondition.column` and `groupByCondition.value` expect an object such as `groupByCondition = {"column": "col1", "value": "abc"}` but yours comes in a different way `groupByCondition = {"col1": "abc"}`.

You can either change the `groupByCondition` object to fit the way you access it later:

```js
allRecords = [{"col1": "abc", "col2": "xyz"}, {"col1": "cde", "col2": "zxy"}, {"col1": "1", "col2": "bit"}, {"col1": 1, "col2": "byte"}];

function filterRecords(condition) {
  result = allRecords.filter(
    function(r){
      return r[condition.column] == condition.value;
    }
  );
                                             
  console.log('The result of filtering by '+JSON.stringify(condition)+' is');
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

result = filterRecords({"column": "col1", "value": "abc"});
result = filterRecords({"column": "col1", "value": "cde"});
result = filterRecords({"column": "col1", "value": "1"});
result = filterRecords({"column": "col1", "value": 1});
```

Or you can change the way you access it to fit the condition object:

```js
allRecords = [{"col1": "abc", "col2": "xyz"}, {"col1": "cde", "col2": "zxy"}, {"col1": "1", "col2": "bit"}, {"col1": 1, "col2": "byte"}];

function filterRecords(condition) {
  key = Object.keys(condition)[0];
  result = allRecords.filter(
    function(r){
      return r[key] == condition[key];
    }
  );
                                             
  console.log('The result of filtering by '+JSON.stringify(condition)+' is');
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

result = filterRecords({"col1": "abc"});
result = filterRecords({"col1": "cde"});
result = filterRecords({"col1": 1});
result = filterRecords({"col1": "1"});
```

Both examples assume you filter the records based on the value of only 1 column/attribute. If you want to filter them based on multiple criteria you'll need extra work.